# Printing order of elements in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, iteration, python-2.x

The Dictionary parm should contain all the keys `['f', 'r', 'b', 'l', 't','u']` and only then the below should happen. The below mentioned iteration prints in an unexpected order, please correct what's wrong.

```
parm = {'r':'r', 'l':'l', 't':'t', 'u':'u', 'f':'f', 'b':'b'}
if all(key in parm for key in ['f', 'r', 'b', 'l', 't','u']):
  parm = [_ for _ in parm.values() for i in range(0,9)]
  print (parm)
```

Returns:

```
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't']
```

Expected:

```
['f',  'f',  'f',  'f',  'f',  'f',  'f',  'f',  'f',  'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u',]
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary. And your code is still invalid.

Comment: Update the code, it is valid now

Comment: The order of items in a dictionary was undefined in versions of Python before 3.6. To preserve order in earlier versions use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a regular `dict`.

Comment: You appear to be depending on fetching dictionary values in a certain order.  Dictionaries don't work that way in all but the most recent versions of Python (which 2.x certainly isn't).

Comment: Also, why did you expect the values to be returned in that order?  That's how they're ordered in the list, but so what?  That has no connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension produces items according to the order of the values of the `parm` dict (which is pretty arbitrary prior to Python 3.6), so naturally it won't follow the order of the keys you use in the condition for the `if` statement. If you want the keys to be reordered in the same way as the keys used in the condition you should make it a separate list and use it for both the condition and the list comprehension:

```
parm = {'r':'r', 'l':'l', 't':'t', 'u':'u', 'f':'f', 'b':'b'}
keys = ['f', 'r', 'b', 'l', 't','u']
if all(key in parm for key in keys):
  parm = [parm[key] for key in keys for i in range(0,9)]
  print (parm)
```

Comment: Good alternative to using `collections.OrderedDict` (which might not be possible in all circumstances).